# Mapbox, marker drag, wrong circle range

Tags: mapbox

I've made some simple mapbox scripting on my website, I draw draggable marker and circle around it, after drag stops I redraw circle, but It seems that range ( which is contstant value ) vary depending on lat/lng ...

Codes that I use:

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/7fmox75c/1/][1]
```

Is this my mistake, or is it mapbox bug ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug or a mistake.

Mapbox maps, like many web maps (Google, Bing, etc), use a [Mercator projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection) for displaying the round surface of the earth on the flat surface of your screen. Doing this involves distorting the scale of shapes on the map in order to keep the east/west and north/south directions consistent for all parts of the map. [Here is an animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPQZ7NcQ6YQ) illustrating the distortion from globe to Mercator. Notice how the parts of the globe closer to the poles become much larger than the parts near the equator.

In the image below, each of the circles represent the same amount of area on Earth, even though they look very different due to the distortion of the projection. As you move your marker around the map it is resized in terms of pixels on the screen, but in terms of real-world distance as represented on the map the size of the circle is staying the same.

[image]